# WebComponents: Firefox custom-element is not showing

Tags: javascript, firefox, web-component, custom-element

I am using web components "custom elements" feature and need to support old browsers(Firefox v60), so instead of loading the polyfills via webcomponent-loader.js which loads all the polyfills . lazy loaded custom-elementpolyfill based on feature detection

```js
(function() {
if(!window.customElements){
var ce = document.createElement('script');
ce.type = 'text/javascript';
ce.async = true;
ce.src = 'https://unpkg.com/@webcomponents/custom-elements@1.2.4/custom-elements.min.js';
/**

     * loading "customElement" polyfills wont't fire "WebComponentsReady" event, it will be called when we use
     * "webcomponent-loader.js" but it will load other polyfills("shadow-dom"), so loading the "customElements" polyfill alone
     * based on feature detection and firing "WebComponentsReady" event manually.
     */
  ce.onload = function() {
      document.dispatchEvent(
          new CustomEvent('WebComponentsReady', {bubbles: true}));
  };
  var st = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  st.parentNode.insertBefore(ce, st);
}
})()
```

and fired`WebComponentsReady` event manually when its loaded. Registered the element like below

```js
let registerElement = () => {
 if(!window.customElements.get(“wc-button")){
   window.customElements.define(‘wc-button', WCButton);
 }
};

if(window.customElements){
  registerElement();
 } else {
  document.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', registerElement);
}
```

WebComponentsReadygot fired and in the listener callback has been called to define/register the element, but the element isn't getting shown or loaded in the page in firefox60.6.1esr (64-bit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

webcomponents-loader.js does feature detection for you
instead of waiting for WebComponentsReady event, you do

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
<script>
window.WebComponents.waitFor(() => {
   // do stuff that needs the polyfill
})
</script>
```

For more information:

Comment: 1.This line will break when `window.WebComponents.waitFor` line executed before the `webcomponents-loader` script gets loaded.
2. `webcomponents-loader` load all the polyfills like custom element, shadow-dom, shady-css, In my usecase I need only custom-element. so using the loader will load redundant resources(shadow-dom, shadycss)

Comment: webcomponents-loader.js should be loaded synchronously, before your other scripts.

it will only load the polyfills that are needed. So on modern browsers, it basically just calls the `waitFor` callback, but for legacy browsers, it uses feature detection to decide which polyfills to load.

Answer (score 0):

HTMLElement can be extended only when Custom Elements are implemented (either natively on with a polyfill).

As a consequence you must define the `<wc-button>` custom element class only after the polyfill is loaded.

In your example:

```
let registerElement = () => {
    if(!window.customElements.get("wc-button")){
         //define the WCButton class here
         class WCButton extends HTMLElement {
             //...
         }
         window.customElements.define(‘wc-button', WCButton);
    }
};
```